# How to run application found in sub-module from root module?

Tags: java, maven

Given the following Maven project:

- root-project

  - database
  - server

I am able to configure `maven-exec-plugin` inside the `server` sub-module to run the application found therein. However, if someone updates a peer sub-module (e.g. `database`) then I get runtime errors. What I would like to do instead is have some mechanism that would:

1. Build root-project and its sub-modules when I build the "current project". I don't mind which project this is, it could be `root-project` or `server`.
2. Runs `server` when I run the "current project"

This way, I can initiate all project-wide operations from a single point instead of having to context-switch between the two projects.

I tried configuring `maven-exec-plugin` at `root-project` to do this, but `<classpath/>` resolves to `root-project`'s classpath instead of the desired `server` classpath.

I'm wondering if approaching this from the opposite end is possible (configuring `maven-compiler-plugin` in `server` to build `root-project` and its dependencies) but I'm not sure how to do so. I am also worried that this might set off an endless loop as `root-project` tries building `server` and `server` tries building `root-project`.

Comment: Best is to make a separate module which is intended for execution your project and you have to define the dependencies to your two other modules afterwards you can run it from the root level...in the Parent will not work, cause the parent is executed first in the build order...BTW: What kind of project is this? JEE / Spring Boot ?

Comment: BTW: Why do you like to execute via exec-maven-plugin a server project? Shouldn't that deployed to an application server ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using Jetty. No application server here. I don't understand your suggestion about creating a separate module which is intended for execution. Can you please post a formal answer with `pom.xml` for each module?

Comment: Jetty /is/ an application server...

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correct, it looks like any other project to me:

I've created a project available from https://github.com/johanwitters/stackoverflow-mavenExec

- Parent: stackoverflow-mavenExec
- Child module 1: database
- Child module 2: server

Module "database" has 1 class com.johanw.stackoverflow.database.Database defined as:

```
package com.johanw.stackoverflow.database;

public class Database {
    public static String DATBASE_NAME = "The name";
}
```

Module "server" depends on module "database".

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.johanw.stackoverflow.mavenExec</groupId>
    <artifactId>database</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Module "server" has a exec-maven-plugin plugin defined as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install</id>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>com.johanw.stackoverflow.server.Test</mainClass>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This runs the class com.johanw.stackoverflow.server.Test available from "server", which is defined as:

```
package com.johanw.stackoverflow.server;

import com.johanw.stackoverflow.database.Database;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + Database.DATBASE_NAME);
    }
}
```

You mentioned "I don't mind which project this is, it could be root-project or server". So, for the above to work, you'll need to build the root project. When you do, root (parent) project stackoverflow-mavenExec using ...

```
mvn clean install
```

... it will eventually run the com.johanw.stackoverflow.server.Test and output

```
Hello The name
```

As illustrated below:

[image]

If you want to only run the server main class, from within the root directory, run the follwing command.

```
mvn exec:java -pl server -Dexec.mainClass=com.johanw.stackoverflow.server.Test
```

If it's your goal to switch between clean install and run server, then you can remove the definition of exec-maven-plugin in the server pom, and run respectively:

```
mvn clean install
```

and

```
mvn exec:java -pl server -Dexec.mainClass=com.johanw.stackoverflow.server.Test
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Ah. That's not what I meant but that's one heck of an excellent attempt :) I want the build and run steps to be separate actions. When I run `mvn install` I expect it to build all modules. When I run `mvn exec:exec` I expect it to run the server. And I expect to be able to run these commands against the same module. I hope that clarifies things :)

Comment: Ok. Understand. How about running the server with

mvn exec:java -pl server -Dexec.mainClass=com.johanw.stackoverflow.server.Test

(I added it in the answer)